# Add key/values to dictionary using condition

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, conditional-statements

I have a list of items that I'm adding to dictionary below:

```
COLS = ['CUST', 'MODEL', 'SN', 'DATE', 'CHARGE', 'QTY', 'TOTAL']
with open('UserfeeInvoicing.csv', 'r') as infile:
    ranpak_dict = {
        row[2]: dict(zip(COLS, row)) for row in csv.reader(infile)
    }
```

Is there anyway to only add the records that have `CHARGE =/= 0` or `CHARGE > 0`

Comment: Can you clarify the condition? `CHARGE > 0` already implies `CHARGE != 0` - do you mean  `CHARGE >= 0` ?

Comment: @Lisa: I think they are just two examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use `csv.reader()`, use [`csv.DictReader()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). That object makes it a lot easier to both create your dictionaries and to filter the rows; your code, refactored to use `DictReader()`, looks like this:

```
COLS = ['CUST', 'MODEL', 'SN', 'DATE', 'CHARGE', 'QTY', 'TOTAL']
with open('UserfeeInvoicing.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames=COLS)
    ranpak_dict = {row['SN']: row for row in reader}
```

The `csv.DictReader()` object does *exactly* what your `dict(zip(COLS, row))` call does; build a dictionary from each row, given a sequence of fieldnames.

Filtering in a list, dict or set comprehension works just like adding additional loops; just add `if <condition>` to the loop:

```
ranpak_dict = {row['SN']: row for row in reader if int(row['CHARGE']) > 0}
```

Note the `int()` call; I am assuming that the `CHARGE` column *always* contains digits.

If your textual fields are all quoted, you could also set [`quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC), at which point all columns without quotes are automatically converted to `float` for you. That'd reduce the code to:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames=COLS, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
ranpak_dict = {row['SN']: row for row in reader if row['CHARGE'] > 0}
```

Comment: I really like this solution, and am trying to utilize it.  However in the dictionary creation I am getting syntax errors.  It's expecting an Else, after the If statement.

Comment: @AlliDeacon: no, I was missing the value expression in the dict comprehension; corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
ranpak_dict = {}
COLS = ['CUST', 'MODEL', 'SN', 'DATE', 'CHARGE', 'QTY', 'TOTAL']

with open('UserfeeInvoicing.csv', 'r') as infile:      

    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:

        if float(row[COLS.index('CHARGE')]) >= 0:
            ranpak_dict[row[2]] = dict(zip(COLS, row))
```